# Raspberry Pi 2 stops booting after the message “Starting Kernel”

Tags: pi-2, kernel, boot-issues, archlinux, arm

This is what I have done till now:

1. Flashed a sd card with arch linux image for my raspberry pi 2. I have followed instructions as mentioned [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2).
2. So far so good, my raspberry pi 2 boots properly with this image.
3. Then, I wanted to install a custom kernel and hence I have downloaded the kernel (kernel version 4.4.31;this is the version used in the above mentioned arch image) from kernel.org
4. I followed instructions as mentioned [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Upstream_Kernel_Compilation) to compile the kernel.
5. Once I install the compiled kernel, raspberry pi 2 is not booting. U-boot starts and it starts the kernel with message "Starting Kernel..."and nothing comes after that.....

I have tried all possible things that I can think of but still it is not working.. Can anyone please suggest me what could be the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I think your kernel is crashed or boot cannot find where the kernel locates but it is too broad to say why it is stopped until actually have a look at it carefully with many possibilities.

If you haven't modified kernel, then it may have a problem with partition or SD card itself.

If you are just aiming to boot OS, I suggest you simply use "[NOOBS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)" to boot what Raspberry supports

Below is my booting log and I don't think your kernel didn't actually started.

```
[  OK  ] Found device /dev/mmcblk0p6.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p6...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[    5.884576] systemd-fsck[248]: fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
[    5.886372] systemd-fsck[248]: /dev/mmcblk0p6: 121 files, 10342/32183 clusters
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p6.
         Mounting /boot...
[  OK  ] Created slice system-systemd\x2drfkill.slice.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0...
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status of rfkill0.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-ifup.slice.
[  OK  ] Mounted /boot.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces....
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
         Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed)...
         Starting LSB: Prepare console...
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Prepare console.
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
         Starting LSB: Set console font and keymap...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Raise network interfaces..
         Starting ifup for wlan0...
[  OK  ] Started ifup for wlan0.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Switch to ondemand cpu governor (unless shift key is pressed).
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
         Starting Restore Sound Card State...
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting Regular background program processing daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
         Starting An object/document-oriented database...
[  OK  ] Started An object/document-oriented database.
         Starting Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART...
         Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting LSB: Starts and stops Wicd...
         Starting LSB: triggerhappy hotkey daemon...
         Starting LSB: The X Display Manager...
         Starting LSB: Autogenerate and use a swap file...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
         Starting System Logging Service...
[  OK  ] Started Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Started dhcpcd on all interfaces.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: triggerhappy hotkey daemon.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: The X Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Autogenerate and use a swap file.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
         Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
         Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
[  OK  ] Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting LSB: Start NTP daemon...
         Starting LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons...
         Starting LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd)...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
My IP address is 172.30.1.32
[  OK  ] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Light Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
         Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Currently, I have not modified the linux kernel, but I will do it once I successfully compile and run it on rasberry pi 2. Can you give some pointers to debug this? Or Do you have any steps to compile and install custom kernel on raspberry pi 2?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried this, but this is not for the main stream kernel :(

Comment: http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/raspberry/buildkernel/

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, I have checked this as well and this is also for raspberry pi kernel. I want to compile mainstream kernel and install it on raspberry pi 2.

Comment: the way compiling for mainstream kernel is not much different to raspberry  one.

Comment: Steps might not be different. But, what  configuration files and dts/dtb files to be used is the question.. :(